# PostgreSQL IO Cost logic

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, execution-plan, postgresql-performance

I've been trying to get an IO cost number, similiar to how MS SQL provides it, but in PostgreSQL.

I have read that using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ...`, there will be a `cost` in the output, but the cost corresponds to number of disk page fetches.

However, what I don't understand, is that when I run my example, which is:

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM table`

The result is:

```
                                                     QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on 'table' (cost=0.00..14355.77 rows=652077 width=76) (actual time=0.050..40.275 rows=652077 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.313 ms
 Execution Time: 57.876 ms
(3 rows)
```

So the disk page fetches should be something around 14355.
But when I check the size of table, even including indexes with
`SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('table'));` the size is 75MB.
With a page being 8KB, then the estimated disk page fetches should be:

`75 000 / 8 = 9375`

So how come that when I use`EXPLAIN` I get the cost of 14355? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-BASICS) in the manual the complete formula for the cost value also includes a CPU part that is calculated per row

> The estimated cost is computed as (disk pages read * seq_page_cost) + (rows scanned * cpu_tuple_cost). By default, seq_page_cost is 1.0 and cpu_tuple_cost is 0.01

The above is the formula for a Seq Scan thus the cost value for sequential I/O is used. If random I/O is involved (e.g. index scans), you need to replace `seq_page_cost` with `random_page_cost`.

So in your example the planner estimates 652077 rows which results in an added cost value of ~6520. Adding that to your estimate of 9375 results in 15895 which is a bit higher than your plan shows, so maybe the number of pages is a bit smaller. The estimated number of pages is taken from `pg_class.relpages` if I'm not mistaken.

I usually dot not really care about the cost value to be honest. The number of estimated rows and the overal "plan strategy" is way more interesting in my opinion. Most of the time use `explain (analyze, buffers)` anyway so that I can easily pinpoint the slowest operations in the plan.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part of documentation. I appreciate your answer very much. Thank you, kind stranger.